# How do you get lower and upper bounds from scipy.stats.distributions objects?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

I have a scipy.stats.distributions object, and I'm trying to figure out its lower and upper bounds. Simplified code to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
from scipy.stats.distributions import uniform
u = uniform(1, 5)
print u.dist.name              #prints 'uniform'
print u.dist.lower_bound       #I'm trying to print '1'
#AttributeError: 'uniform_gen' object has no attribute 'lower_bound'
```

I couldn't find documentation anywhere for how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that all of the scipy distributions are parameterised for the greatest convenience of the greatest number of us. However, the documentation says, 'This distribution is constant between loc and loc + scale.' You want a uniform on the interval [1,5], which implies loc=1 and loc+scale=5. Then we can get what you've asked for most directly with the following code.

```
>>> from scipy.stats.distributions import uniform
>>> u = uniform(1,4)
>>> u.ppf(0)
1.0
>>> u.ppf(1)
5.0
```

Life becomes more uncertain where distributions with infinite support are involved, such as the normal. You can ask for, say, ppf(0) and/or ppf(1) but the results (minus and plus infinity are not very interesting). I suspect that most of would be more interested in lower and upper 'bounds' that capture the 'interesting' part of the density function. In the case of the normal this might be from ppf(0.05) to ppf(0.95). In this case, the documentation says, 'The location (loc) keyword specifies the mean. The scale (scale) keyword specifies the standard deviation.' Which is a relief.

```
>>> from scipy.stats.distributions import norm
>>> n = norm(0,1)
>>> n.ppf(0.05)
-1.6448536269514729
>>> n.ppf(0.95)
1.6448536269514722
```

No surprise.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, probability density functions do not have upper/lower bounds x-wise or y-wise. By definition, your uniform distribution would have its pdf evaluated as 1/4 over the range (1, 5) and 0 every where else. If you are asking for the point at which cdf is 0 or 1 (or asymptotically close to 0 or 1), then every distribution function in `scipy.stats` has a `ppf` method, with which you can use to get the upper/lower bound by putting in a desired percentile (in your case, 0 and 1).

Note, however, that continuous random variables in general will give you +-infinity as one or both of its bounds when you put 0 or 1 into `ppf`. That is just how distributions are built. If you insist on finding a value, then try some number close to but not actually 0 or 1.